# Any idea how to fix this? Exception in thread "WindowsNativeRunloopThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, openjfx

My application uses javafx 11.0.1 and is shipped bundled with a jlinked version of openjdk 11. It runs fine for the vast majority of the users but few of them are getting this stack:

```
Exception in thread "WindowsNativeRunloopThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.staticScreen_getScreens(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.initScreens(Screen.java:412)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:152)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.assignScreensAdapters(QuantumToolkit.java:695)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runToolkit(QuantumToolkit.java:313)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$startup$10(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:153)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found some discussion related to the same exception but regarding Maven+Eclipse, [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg14667.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906570/javafx-11-using-maven-throws-exception-windowsnativerunloopthread). The issue is very similar, user reporting it, do have other java installations and uninstalling them solves the issue, so basically leaving my bundled openjdk as the only option the application starts, but if there is another Java installed on the system, the wrong .dll is picked up and the application crashes with the above stacktrace.

I tried the suggested `java.library.path` workaround but users are saying it doesn't solve. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it myself, any idea on how to solve it or what to ask the users reporting it?

**EDIT**: we fixed the exe generated by lauch4j [here](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/commit/a729b6213ed12a9933855766e8f0f3f3549cb6dd) and the bash script [here](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/issues/357). The idea is basically to restrict/change the `PATH` env variable to avoid the wrong dll being picked up.

Comment: Can you clarify how do you run `jlink` and how do you set the runtime options?

Comment: Have you tried updating to JDK 11.0.2?

Comment: I haven't tried the latest openjdk or openjfx yet. I run jlink as shown here https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/blob/058d51f0968862af353456f242b025e1b8ae04ef/pdfsam-basic/pom.xml in the jlink execution. You can run it with an exe generated by launch4j or using a batch
      "%JAVACMD%" -jar "%JAR_ARG%" %JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx512M -Dapp.name="pdfsam-basic" -Dprism.lcdtext=false -Dapp.home="%BASEDIR%" -Dbasedir="%BASEDIR%" org.pdfsam.basic.App %CMD_LINE_ARGS% as show here https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/blob/0d883bc47dab3075e9c6e37fde888206bf953063/pdfsam-basic/src/assembly/resources/bin/pdfsam.bat

Comment: The `jlink` tool creates _platform-specific_ images. Are the users who are having problems using a different platform than the image was built for?

Comment: @Slaw No, they are using the Windows version. Uninstalling the Java 8 they have on the system fixes the issue and the application starts happily

Comment: I have the same issue, without any jlink setup at all, using AdoptOpenJDK 12.0.2 in IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed the exe generated by lauch4j [here](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/commit/a729b6213ed12a9933855766e8f0f3f3549cb6dd) and the bash script [here](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/issues/357). The idea is basically to restrict/change the `PATH` env variable to avoid the wrong dll being picked up.